# using awk with variables

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, variable

I am making a word list from all the words typed into a program that will be working with the text entered into it.  I want to use a stream editor like sed or awk to search the first word of every line in a document and return the line number when a pattern -stored in a variable- is found. I have this much **working correctly** so far:

```
awk $1 '{print $1 " " NR""}' dictionary.txt | awk '/^**myWord** /' | cut -d" " -f2
```

However, I cannot figure out how to use a variable in place of "myWord". For example, I get only errors when I use:

```
read=searchWord

awk $1 '{print $1 " " NR""}' words.txt | awk '/^**$searchWord** /' | cut -d" " -f2
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Variable expansion will not happen inside of a single quoted `'` string.  Try:

```
searchWord="myWord"
awk $1 '{print $1 " " NR""}' words.txt | awk '/^**'"$searchWord"'** /' | cut -d" " -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk -v`

```
-v var=val
--assign var=val
    Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  
    Such variable values are  available  to  the  BEGIN block of an AWK program.
```

Comment: Note that this is not supported everywhere, I remember e.g. that the `awk` that came with OS X did not support this.